# How to separate a column into two, using account numbers that vary in length

Tags: ssms

I am just trying to learn how to separate data in a column. Let me use an example:

```
create table bad_data (
ID varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('48393Johnny')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('48333Alex')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('71593Mike')
```

I understand that if I wanted to separate the column into an ID and a first name, I could use

```
select substring(ID, 1, 5) as ID, substring(ID, 6,100) as FIRSTNAME FROM bad_data;
```

This query will give me the desired separation into two columns of the ID and the first name for IDs in length of 5 characters.

HOWEVER, the question I have is this; what if the account numbers vary in size? So, for example, if we had data with larger account numbers:

```
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('48393Johnny')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('48333Alex')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('71593Mike')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('761545Peter')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('761975David')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('482545Patrick')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('974126Joshua')
INSERT INTO bad_data VALUES ('348521Tommy')
```

You will notice that going down the list past Mike, the account numbers are now 6 instead of 5 in character length. What query could we write to separate the first name still from the account numbers? I appreciate any and all feedback. I will be actively continuing to research, but please feel free to send any input as all is greatly appreciated.

I have included my table I created as well as the question.

Comment: *"what if the account numbers vary in size?"* - cant we find the last occuring integer using `patindex`?

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue using [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and match the first occuring alphabet (excluding numbers) using regex. The function returns the first index of a matching pattern.

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(ID, 0, PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', ID) - 1) as ID,
  SUBSTRING(ID, PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', ID),100) as FIRSTNAME
FROM bad_data;
```

See fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/23kAzytA